# Changing what internal video card my laptop uses

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, laptop, integrated

I hope I explain this correctly, because I have no idea what I'm talking about:

I ran two commands in the terminal to find out what graphics card my laptop uses, and got this result:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

$ sudo lshw -C video
*-display UNCLAIMED     
    description: 3D controller
    product: GM108M [GeForce 840M]
    vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
    version: a2
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:b5000000-b5ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128)
*-display
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
    version: 06
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
    resources: irq:30 memory:b7000000-b73fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:7000(size=64)
```

Three questions about this:

1. Am I correct in assuming that my laptop has an Intel integrated
   graphics controller, **and** a Nvidia graphics card?
2. Am I correct in assuming that my computer right now only uses the Intel controller?
3. How do I go about making it use the Nvidia card instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What labtob do you have? I guess you have a Nvidia Optimus, a hybrid solution which ueses the intel gfx as long as you run non 3D application and the nvidia 840m gfx as soon as you need 3D acceleration

Comment: @cmks It's a HP Envy Notebook. I can't find the model, as it has been put out of production, but if it's really important to answer the question I think I can find a way to find it.

Comment: You need the exact model if you want to research if it has two independed gfx-cards or a hyprid solution like nvidia optimus

Comment: @cmks I dug up my receit and found the model, HP ENVY 15-j160no Notebook PC. The [HP product page](http://support.hp.com/se-sv/document/c04395041#AbT0) only mentions the Nvidia card, but why would an Intel integrated graphics controller pop up in the terminal if the laptop only has the Nvidia card?

Comment: The product page also list the intel gfx card in the row of the processor. But there is no information if  it is nvidia optimus or dual-gfx